# Is this behavior normal or is it a bug? Training with incompatible shapes in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have found a weird behavior in tensorflow.keras, it doesn't occur in the classic keras. 
I have these shapes in my dataset.

```
x_train = np.random.rand(60,3,1)
y_train = np.random.rand(60,1)
```

And this LSTM network

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(120,input_shape=(3,1)))
model.add(Dense(2,activation="relu"))
model.compile(loss="MSE",optimizer="adam")
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1)
model.summary()
```

It's supposed this shouldn't work because the output of the network is (,2) and y_train is (,1). But it start training.[image]

But using the classic keras it fails, as I expected.

```
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from keras import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(120,input_shape=(3,1)))
model.add(Dense(2,activation="relu"))
model.compile(loss="MSE",optimizer="adam")
model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1)
model.summary()
```

[image]

The version are, and I'm using Google Colab:

- Tensorflow: 2.2.0
- Keras: 2.3.1

What could be causing this? Is this a bug or a new feature?